# How can I dismiss my DimmingView and SlideMenu at once?

Tags: swift

I created a slide menu with a dimming view. When the user taps outside the side menu I want the slide menu and the dimming view to dismiss. How can I achieve this exactly? I already created a TapRecognizer in each class and it works.. but only for each class at once. [Here](https://pastebin.com/cpQxcEYf) is my MenuController and below is my SlideTransition with my dimming view. Right now it removes the dimming view when I click outside the slide menu. But it should also removes the slide menu.

```
class SlideinTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

let menuViewController = MenuViewController()

var isPresenting = true
let dimmingView = UIView()

func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return 0.6
}

@objc func touchWasDetected() {
    print("Touch detected")
    dimmingView.removeFromSuperview()
    menuViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    guard let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to),
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) else { return }
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

    let finalWidth = toViewController.view.bounds.width * 0.3
    let finalHeight = toViewController.view.bounds.height

    if isPresenting{

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchWasDetected))
        dimmingView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        //adds the dimming view
        dimmingView.backgroundColor = .black
        dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
        containerView.addSubview(dimmingView)
        dimmingView.frame = containerView.bounds
        //adds the menu view controller to our container
        containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)

        //init frame off the screen
        toViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: -finalWidth, y: 0, width: finalWidth, height: finalHeight)
    }

    let transform = {
        self.dimmingView.alpha = 0.5
        toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: finalWidth, y: 0)
    }

    let identity = {
        self.dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
        fromViewController.view.transform = .identity
    }

    //animates the transition
    let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
    let isCancelled = transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
        self.isPresenting ? transform() : identity()
    }) { (_) in
        transitionContext.completeTransition(!isCancelled)
    }
}
```

}

Side menu and dimming view should both be removed when the user taps outside the side menu/ on the dimming view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you are using `SlideinTransition` for present and dismiss. 
So you should move `dimmingView.removeFromSuperview()` from `touchWasDetected()` to `UIView.animate` completion.

**UPD:**
I've run this on sample project, works fine.

initial controller:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    let transition = SlideinTransition()

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        segue.destination.transitioningDelegate = self
    }

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transition.isPresenting = true
        return transition
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transition.isPresenting = false
        return transition
    }
}
```

modified Transitioning:

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    @IBAction func dismissControllerAnimated() {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}

class SlideinTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    var isPresenting = true
    let dimmingView = UIView()

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.6
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        guard let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to),
              let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) else { return }
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        let finalWidth = toViewController.view.bounds.width * 0.3
        let finalHeight = toViewController.view.bounds.height

        if isPresenting {
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: toViewController, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissControllerAnimated))
            dimmingView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

            //adds the dimming view
            dimmingView.backgroundColor = .black
            dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
            containerView.addSubview(dimmingView)
            dimmingView.frame = containerView.bounds
            //adds the menu view controller to our container
            containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)

            //init frame off the screen
            toViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: -finalWidth, y: 0, width: finalWidth, height: finalHeight)
        }

        let transform = {
            self.dimmingView.alpha = 0.5
            toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: finalWidth, y: 0)
        }

        let identity = {
            self.dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
            fromViewController.view.transform = .identity
        }

        //animates the transition
        let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        let isCancelled = transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.isPresenting ? transform() : identity()
        }) { (_) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!isCancelled)
            if !self.isPresenting {
                self.dimmingView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is it only dismissed the dimming view and not the slide menu.. it should remove both at once

Answer (score 0):

I know im really late to the party but I faced this problem and I think I found a good solution

first add a gesture recogniser to the dim view

```
  let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchWasDetected))
        dimView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

then create a protocol to pass the event

```
protocol DimViewTouchDetectedProtocol: AnyObject {
func close()
```

}

add a weak delegate to the SlideinTransition

```
    weak var delegate: DimViewTouchDetectedProtocol?
```

and call the close func of the delegate in the gesture func

```
@objc func touchWasDetected() {
    delegate?.close()
}
```

assign the delegate to the class (the menu or popupOver)

```
menuViewController.delegate = self
```

implement the method and call self.dismiss in the method body and you're good to go

```
    extension SavePopupViewController: DimViewTouchDetectedProtocol {
func close() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
}
```